# Accelerating inclined plane with friction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors, free-body-diagram

So I've been having trouble with an exercise involving an inclined plane.
As shown in the figure, the inclined plane is being **accelerated** by the force F and, between the inclined plane and the box, **there is a static friction μs**.
[image]

It's asked for the **maximum system acceleration** possible in which there will be **no movement between the inclined plane and the box**, the force F to "produce" this acceleration and the Normal force done by the inclined plane over the box.

The think is, I don't know if the free body diagram for the box and my answers are correct.
I'll let my attempt below.
[image]
$$
\sum F_y~=~0\\\\N\cdot cos(\theta)-m\cdot g+\mu\cdot N\cdot sen(\theta)~=~0\\\\\boxed{m\cdot g~=~N\cdot \left(cos(\theta)+\mu\cdot sen(\theta)\right)}\\\\\\\sum F_x~=~0\\\\-m\cdot a+N\cdot sen(\theta)+\mu\cdot N\cdot cos(\theta)~=~0\\\\\boxed{m\cdot a~=~N\cdot \left(sen(\theta)+\mu\cdot cos(\theta)\right)} 
$$
.
$$
\dfrac{m\cdot a}{m\cdot g}~=~\dfrac{N\cdot \left(sen(\theta)+\mu\cdot cos(\theta)\right)}{N\cdot \left(cos(\theta)+\mu\cdot sen(\theta)\right)}\\\\\dfrac{a}{g}~=~\dfrac{sen(\theta)+\mu\cdot cos(\theta)}{cos(\theta)+\mu\cdot sen(\theta)}\\\\\boxed{a~=~g\cdot\dfrac{sen(\theta)+\mu\cdot cos(\theta)}{cos(\theta)+\mu\cdot sen(\theta)}}
$$
.
$$
F~=~(m+M)\cdot a\\\\\boxed{F~=~(m+M)\cdot g\cdot \dfrac{sen(\theta)+\mu\cdot cos(\theta)}{cos(\theta)+\mu\cdot sen(\theta)}}
$$
.
$$
\boxed{N~=~\dfrac{m\cdot g}{cos(\theta)+\mu\cdot sen(\theta)}}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let's, first of all, focus on the motion of the smaller block placed on the inclined surface. Its free body diagram is as shown below. Assume that the force applied on the incline and surface produces an acceleration 'a' so that there is a pseudo force (of magnitude 'ma') acting on the smaller block.

The magnitude of normal reaction is equal to the total force acting normally at the contact surface between two solids.

[image]

[image]